# Android Notepad Uri Explanation

Tags: sql, android, sqlite, uri

In the android Notes demo, it accepts the URI:

```
    sUriMatcher.addURI(NotePad.AUTHORITY, "notes", NOTES);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(NotePad.AUTHORITY, "notes/#", NOTE_ID);
```

Where the difference between notes and notes/# is that notes/# returns the note who's ID matches #.

However, the managedQuery() method that is used to get data from the content provider has the following parameters:

```
Parameters
uri The URI of the content provider to query.
projection  List of columns to return.
selection   SQL WHERE clause.
selectionArgs   The arguments to selection, if any ?s are pesent
sortOrder   SQL ORDER BY clause.
```

So, is there any particular cause for the design decision of providing a URI for that, rather than just using the selection parameter?  Or is it just a matter of taste?

Thank you.

Comment: could you link to the demo? I've never seen it.

Comment: Here you go: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html, it's in the notepadproviderclass (which is in the src directory, followed by a bunch of subdirectories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks its so you can do more complex lookups without having to complicate your selections and arguments. For example in my project I have multiple tables but use the same selection and arguments. To filter content. By using the URI I don't have interpret the query, I can just switch on the URI. It.might be personal taste to begin with. But in more complex scenarios you appreciate the URI. You can also use * to match strings in the same.way you can with#.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's mostly a matter of taste. IMHO, putting the id in the Uri is a little cleaner since you can make the id opaque rather than require the client to know that it actually represents a specific row id. For instance, you can pass a lookup key (like in the the Contacts API) rather than a specific row id.

Comment: I thought of that, and I agree that it would be a bit cleaner, but for the user to understand the cursor that they're getting back, they need to know a bit (aka, what columns there are) about the underlying structure.